# Solving a Complex Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Can anyone tell me how to solve: Solve the equation $z^3-2z^2+(7+2i)z-6(2-i) = 0$ given that $z = 2-i$ is a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You divide the whole polynomial by $z-2+i$ and solve the remaining quadratic equation $z^2-iz+6$ using the quadratic formula or some factoring trick $(z+2i)(z-3i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to (synthetic) division is to let the other roots be $z_1,z_2$, then by Vieta's formulas:

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 + z_2 + (2-i) & = 2 \\
z_1 z_2 (2-i) & = 6(2-i)
\end{align}
$$

Therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 + z_2 & = i \\
z_1 z_2 & = 6
\end{align}
$$

So $z_1,z_2$ are the roots of the quadratic $z^2 - i z + 6 = 0$.

Comment: Nice alternative approach.